# Java functional programming: create list of object from a different list

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'd like to convert to funcional programming the following method:

```
public static List<PayrollEntry> payroll(List<Employee> employees) {
    List<PayrollEntry> payrollEntries = new ArrayList<PayrollEntry>();
    for(Employee emp:employees){

        PayrollEntry pEntry = new PayrollEntry(emp,emp.getSalary(),new BigDecimal(1000));
        payrollEntries.add(pEntry);
    }
    return payrollEntries;
}
```

Someone could show me how can I create an instance of an object based on the current list using functional programming?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `map` and `collect` methods of the stream:

```java
public static List<PayrollEntry> payroll(List<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
                    .map(emp -> new PayrollEntry(emp,emp.getSalary(),new BigDecimal(1000)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Though it would be better to provide better copy constructor in `PayrollEntry`:

```java
public class PayrollEntry {
// ...
    public PayrollEntry(Employee emp) {
        this(emp, emp.getSalary(), new BigDecimal(1000));
   }
// ...
}
```

Then it is possible to use the constructor as a method reference:

```java
public static List<PayrollEntry> payroll(List<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out nulls to prevent NPE
                    .map(PayrollEntry::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, wasn't able to understand how to create the object inside the map method. new PayrollEntry() is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```java
public static List<PayrollEntry> payroll(final List<Employee> employees) {
  return employees.stream()
    .map(emp -> new PayrollEntry(emp, emp.getSalary(), new BigDecimal(1000)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I might be best to pull out the payroll logic into another function (e.g. for testing):

```java
public static PayrollEntry payrollOfEmployee(final Employee employee) {
  return new PayrollEntry(employee, employee.getSalary(), new BigDecimal(1000));
}

public static List<PayrollEntry> payroll(final List<Employee> employees) {
  return employees.stream()
    .map(payrollOfEmployee)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```